# Approaches to creating composite data lists from multiple RESTful sources

Tags: android, design-patterns, retrofit, spotify

Hope this question isn't too high level.
I'm working on an Android Application at the moment that connects to the Spotify Web API (using Retrofit), the end result is a list of tracks which is generated from data collected from other API calls, for example a users top tracks, top artists etc... Because the end result I need is constructed from a few different API calls I'm concerned the logic is a bit messy, at the moment it's essentially:

```
getFirstBitofRequiredData -> onDataReady -> getNextBitofData ->      OnDataReady -> getMoreData(combinedDataSets) -> onDataReady -> createDataModelObjectsForView(moreCombinedDataSets)
```

Something to that effect anyway! I was wondering is there any specific architectural approaches to implementing this kind of sequential and combinational method of getting data?

Thanks in advance,

Garry

Comment: Check RxJava2. It makes quite simple to put all those callbacks in 1 fluent API.

Comment: I'm actually using the RxAndroid adapter for Retrofit to return as Observables but perhaps I'm underutilising them on that front? I'll have another look at their API from a higher level and see if I figure it out. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

That's not gonna be a complete answer, but should help you direct you more on the Rx stuff. The main point is with Rx you can do ALL those actions in line of calls. Meaning, the call-callback will not be spread all over the class and it will be easy to read/understand what's going on.

I'm gonna type a pseudo code, all by heart, so you have to actually dig the docs to see how. But it should point on the example of what u want to achieve.

```
Data1 d1;
Data2 d2;
Data3 d3;

retrofit.getData1(param) // the retrofit observable
        .flatMap(new Function<Data1, ObservableSource<Data2>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Data2> call(Data1 data1){
                   d1 = data1;
                   return retrofit.getData2(data1.val);
            }
         });
        .flatMap(new Function<Data2, ObservableSource<Data3>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Data3> call(Data2 data2){
                   d2 = data2;
                   return retrofit.getData3(data2.val);
            }
         })
         .observeOn(... UI thread)
         .subscribe( ...
              ... now you have all the data here ...
```

Comment: Ah excellent that makes a lot of sense, looks like a very readable and concise way to sequence them as they occur. I'll give that a go today, was going to opt for some usage of combineLatest but I think this makes more sense for the circumstances. Thanks very much!